# Confused about reduced defect measures

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, geometric-measure-theory

I am confused about a certain behaviour of reduced defect measures, and I would like to seek clarification on it. Below are the details.

Let $B$ denote the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $\{f_m\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\subset L^2(B)$ is a uniformly bounded sequence (in the $L^2$-norm) such that
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
f_m\rightarrow f\quad\text{a.e. in }B\\
f_m\rightharpoonup f\quad\text{in }L^2(B)
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation} as $m\rightarrow\infty$. We cannot conclude that $f_m\rightarrow f$ in $L^1(B)$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$. To examine this failure of strong convergence DiPerna and Majda introduce the so called reduced defect measure:
\begin{equation}
\theta(E)\equiv\limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty}\int_{E}|f_m-f|^2\ \mathrm{d}x\quad E\subset B,\ E\text{ is Borel},
\end{equation}which I suppose when defined as:
\begin{equation}
\theta(E)\equiv\inf\left\{\limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty}\int_G|f_m-f|^2\ \mathrm{d}x\ \Big|\ E\subset G, \ G\text{ is Borel}\right\}\quad (\theta\subset B)
\end{equation}gives a measure on $B$. However, $\theta$ fails the countable sub-additivity property in general. I suppose this is because we don't have a mechanism for swapping the limits involved. Nonetheless, $\theta$ is finitely sub-additive.

It seems to me that $\theta$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mathcal{L}^n$, because if $E\subset B$ is such that $|E|=0$, then (as $\mathcal{L}^n$ is Borel regular) there is a Borel set $G$ such that $E\subset G$ and $|G|=0$. Consequently,
\begin{equation}
\int_{G}|f_m-f|^2\ \mathrm{d}x=0\quad\text{for all } m\in\mathbb{N},
\end{equation}and therefore,
\begin{equation}
\theta(E)\leq \limsup_{m\rightarrow\infty}\int_{G}|f_m-f|^2\ \mathrm{d}x=0.
\end{equation}

There is a known theorem in measure theory that says if $\mu$ is a finite measure on a set $X$ and $\{E_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint measureable sets in $X$, then there are at most countably many $E_{\alpha}$ such that $\mu(E_{\alpha})>0$. The proof of this theorem does not call upon the countable sub-additivity property of $\mu$, only finite sub-additivity.

As $\theta$ is finitely sub-additive and $\theta(B)<\infty$, the above theorem is applicable for $\theta$. Thus, if $\theta(B)>0$, and we write
\begin{equation}
B=\bigcup_{y\in B}\{y\},
\end{equation}we have $\{\{y\}\}_{y\in B}$ is a pairwise disjoint collection of measurable sets in $B$ and only countably many are such that $\theta(\{y\})>0$. In particular, there is at least one $\{y\}$ such that $\theta(\{y\})>0$.

However, $|\{y\}|=0$, which in turn should imply that $\theta(\{y\})=0$ - an apparent contradiction.

I would like help figuring out what went wrong with my argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in the line: **... and only countably many are such that $\theta(\{y\})>0$. In particular, there is at least one $\{y\}$ such that $\theta(\{y\})>0$.**

The same issue comes up if you use the Lebesgue measure instead of $\theta$. We can write $B=\bigcup_{y\in B}\{y\}$, and we have $0 < \mathcal{L}^N(B) < \infty$. Do you see the issue with deducing from this that there is at least one point with positive Lebesgue measure? Of course this isn't possible since we can easily show  and $\mathcal{L}^N(\{y\})=0$ for all $y\in B$.

The theorem you reference only says that there are *at most* countably many positive measure sets in your collection. However, it does not guarantee the existence of even one such set.